# запуск бота на python vk_api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот, вконтакте

пытаюсь создать развлекательного бота для бесед вк. Long Poll API включен и совпадает с версией vk_api, там же есть доступ для таких событий как входящие и исходящие сообщения. Есть возможность добавлять бота в беседы. Токен ака ключ доступа сгенерирован также в настройках сообщества. Бот по итогу не работает, не отвечает на сообщения. Возможно что не слушает ивенты т.к. print не выводит ничего в консоль после отправки сообщения? делаю по различным гайдам с ютуба. Заранее спасибо.

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
print("hello")

# Ваш access token
TOKEN = 'vk1.a.b.....'

# Инициализация VK API
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=TOKEN, api_version = 5.95)
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session, group_id=220948206)
session_api = vk_session.get_api()

 #vk_session.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': id, 'message': message, random_id= 0})
# Функция отправки сообщения
def send_message(id, message):
    vk_session.method("messages.send", {"user_id": id, "message": message, "random_id":0})

# Главный цикл обработки событий
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.to_me:
            msg = event.text.lower()
            id = event.user_id
            if msg == "hi":
                send_message (id, "hi friend")
print(msg)
```

Comment: `VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW` -> `VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW` попробуйте. + `print(msg)` нужно поднять на уровень `if event.to_me:`

Comment: да, спасибо, так работает но только в личке сообщества, но как сделать, чтобы бот отвечал в чате, куда его добавили? предполагаю, что сменить на `event.from_chat`, но в таком случае выходит ошибка  `Access denied: no access to call this method. It cannot be called with current scopes.` Для ботов тоже нужно запрашивать разрешение на отправку сообщений как и для Standalone-приложения?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить бота по https://dev.vk.com/api/bots/getting-started?ref=old_portal этой инструкции. Также можно попробовать убрать `group_id=220948206` и `api_version = 5.95`